# How to change useState value while navigating to current page in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the value of collection_name to empty string after navigating to current page in my handleSubmit function after the toast.success message . In my code the page is navigates correctly, but the value is same. I tried using setCollection to null but nothing happened. Please help. Thanks

```
const AddCollection = () => {
  const [collection_name, setCollection] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/addCollection", {
        collection_name,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        toast.success(res.data.message);
        navigate('/addType');
       })
      .catch((err) => {
        //console.log(err.response.data.error);
       toast.error(err.response.data.error)
      });
  }
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Add Book Type</h1>
      <ToastContainer />
      <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="">Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Type.."
              className="form-control"
              name="collection_name"
              onChange={(e) => setCollection(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" className="btn" />
      </form>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default AddCollection;
```

This is my App.js

```
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
    <Route path="/addType" element={<AddCollection />}></Route>
    <Route path="/allType" element={<AllCollection />}></Route>
    <Route path="/add" element={<AddBook />}></Route>
    <Route path="/books" element={<AllBook />}></Route>
    <Route path="/addBookCollection" element={<AddBookCollection />}></Route>
    <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditBook />}></Route>
    <Route path="/type/:name" element={<TypeWiseBook />}></Route>
    <Route path="/search" element={<SearchPage />}></Route>
    <Route path="/book/:id" element={<SingleBook />}></Route>
   </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to `setCollection("")`?

If it's after your `navigate` call, is this component still mounted (i.e. it sits above your Router)? We would need to see more of the app structure to understand the problem.

Comment: @ShabnamSabah i didnt understood why do you want the collection_name to be empty  string, and what worked for and what not?

Comment: @AhmerSaud I want to reset the form after submit where all the values will be empty but now it shows the value which I typed.

Comment: @argbo yes it is after my navigate. I have added my app.js code. please check in the post.

Comment: @ShabnamSabah looks like after submiting the form in handleSubmit function, you are navigating to the same route you are aleady on. So your component doesnt unmount and the state of  collection_name remains as it is.

Comment: type `setCollection("")` instead of `navigate("/AddType")` and set value of your input as collection_name

Answer (score 1):

To start with, navigating to the current page is not the right way to clear state, and is likely not doing anything valuable. If you want to clear state on the current page, call `setCollection("")`. You do not need to `navigate`.

I suspect the problem is that calling `setCollection` after a successful POST works as intended, but you are not using a [Controlled Input](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) so you cannot *see* that it's working.

You should use `collection_name` as your input value, like this:

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter Type.."
  className="form-control"
  name="collection_name"
  onChange={(e) => setCollection(e.target.value)}
  value={collection_name}
/>
```

Here is a minimal working example to get you started. Notice it will work without any `navigate` call.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

export function AddType() {
  const [collection_name, setCollection] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{collection_name}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCollection("");
        }}
      >
        Navigate
      </button>
      <input onChange={(e) => setCollection(e.target.value)} value={collection_name} />
    </div>
  );
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/addType",
    element: <AddType />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```